# Consistent hostname for Docker containers/VM across platforms?

Tags: docker, cross-platform, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that starts my application server. I then use a few different tools to run integration/stress tests against it.

However, on my Mac the application server starts on `localhost`, and on Windows it starts on the VirtualBox VM at `192.168.99.100`.

I've heard that `docker-machine ip` is a cross-platform way to "find" your Docker containers, and it works for Windows:

```
Craig@Work-PC MINGW64 ~
$ docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100
```

But on my Mac:

```
craig$ docker-machine ip
Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists
```

Is there a way to use `docker-machine` or some other *already established* method for finding the container hostname in a cross-platform way?

My goal would be to have this run out-of-the-box without any config on both a new Mac, and new Windows, environment. I can update all my scripts to check for Windows vs Mac (vs Unix), but then I have to duplicate the logic in a bunch of different places.

Comment: Maybe something like this?

"docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name"

or this may be usefull "docker network inspect bridge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker machine provides a wrapper around setting `$DOCKER_HOST` in your environment. So you can check this variable, if it's defined strip off the port number and that's your target IP. And if it's not defined, you can use `localhost`.

Comment: It's populated on Windows (with `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`) but not on Mac - so I think this might work.